# как управлять системой из raw-режима на Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

Необходимо считывать скан-коды клавиш (press и realese отдельно), для этого, как я понимаю необходим raw-режим (`kbd_mode -s`). Мне выдает какие-то квадратики и символы, которые не особ понятны и для выхода в нормальный режим требуется перезагрузка системы.
Вопросы в следующем, как выйти в нормальный режим из `kbd_mode -s`? 
Или подскажите другую возможность считывать скан-коды клавиш в положении up и down?
заранее спасибо!

Comment: консоль или иксы?

Answer (score 0):

В иксах можно прочитать сканкоды клавиш через тест:

```
eri@eri-mini ~% xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA7DB5:00 06CB:7DB7 Touchpad            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam: HD WebCam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
eri@eri-mini ~% xinput test 12
key release 36 
key press   41 
key press   42 
key press   43 
key release 41 
key release 42 
key release 43 
key press   41 
key press   42 
key press   43
```

Окно в фокусе вроде не нужно.

Какие-то квадратики это байты. Там простая структура нажал-отпустил и код клавиши. Чтоб в них разобраться надо загружать байты в структуры. Для этого понадобится си или питон. Выйти из сырого режима можно закрыв программу, но с клавиатуры это врятли получится.

В консоли надо читать event устройство и разбирать структуру байтов которая льётся оттуда. Готовый кейлогер в котором можно посмотреть как всё устроенно [на гитхабе](https://github.com/kernc/logkeys). На баше не выйдет.

Comment: забыл сказать, использую не графический интерфейс, а консоль!!

Comment: консоль внутри графического интерфейса или tty?

Comment: @Илья добавил ссылку на консольный кейлогер. посмотри

Comment: [ScanCodes](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-10.html) see :)